# Why this function returns always 0

Tags: c

I have a problem in this function(`int populationTotal(villes ville[], int n, char nom[])`), I've created a structure of city have a name and number of poeple and name of his country, and I want from the user to gives me a name of country and I'll give him the total of the poeple in this country.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct ville
{
    char nom[50];
    int population;
    char pays[30];
}villes;

void chargement(villes villes[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Entrez le nom de la ville n° %d: \n", i+1);
        gets(villes[i].nom);
        printf("Entrez la population de la ville n° %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &villes[i].population);
        getchar();
        printf("Entrez le pays de la ville n° %d:\n", i+1);
        gets(villes[i].pays);
    }
}

int populationTotal(villes ville[], int n, char nom[])
{
    int Total=0, i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(ville[i].pays, nom))
            Total += ville[i].population;
    }
    return Total;
}
int main()
{
    villes ville[50];
    int n;
    char pays[30];
    printf("Entrez le nombre de villes: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();

    if( n < 1 || n > 50)
        printf("Le nombre doit etre...");
    else
    {
        chargement(ville, n);
        printf("Entrez le pays: \n");
        gets(pays);
        printf("La population total est: %d", populationTotal(ville, n, pays));

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iALkB.png)

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

Comment: The function not always return 0. Example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ieNv4lQYdSUkRbod

Comment: Note that `strcmp()` returns `0` for equality, so you can't use it as if the return value is `true` for a match. See `if(strcmp(ville[i].pays, nom)) Total += ville[i].population;`

Comment: add some values of poeple in each city and try to get the total after

Comment: i used strcmp just for comparing two strings i din't used for get the number of poeple i used ville[].population

Comment: My point stands - you are using `strcmp` as if a non-0 return value means a match, but it means they don't match.

Comment: Did you really want `if(strcmp(ville[i].pays, nom) == 0)` ?

Comment: i want just to see if the name that has the user enters it equal any name of country that there are in my array

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iALkB.png

Comment: In that case please read the documentation for `strcmp` because the error has been pointed out several times.

Comment: Also in `scanf("%d", &villes[i].population);` check the return value from `scanf` to make sure it has actually read the population count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the `pays` string correctly:

```
if(strcmp(ville[i].pays, nom))
```

The `strcmp` function returns 0 if the two strings match and non-zero if they don't match.  Since a conditional is considered true if it evaluates to non-zero, the `if` portion is only entered when `pays` does *not* match each `ville[i].pays`.  And because you entered the same `pays` string for each village as well as the separate `pays` string, they all match so the `if` condition is never entered.

If you entered a different `pays` for one village then the `if` would be entered for that one and you would get a non-zero return value from the function.

You need to compare the result of `strcmp` with 0 to see if the strings match.

```
if(strcmp(ville[i].pays, nom) == 0)
```

Also, [never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) but instead use `fgets`.